# MS SQL Group rows based on start and end

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, group-by

I have a table that looks like this with repeating rows of 3 and 3...

```
Column1      | Column2
CustomerID   | 22
CustomerName | ”ABC”
Responsible  | ”Allan”
CustomerID   | 23
CustomerName | ”DEF”
Responsible  | ”Jessica”
CustomerID   | 24
CustomerName | ”GHI”
Responsible  | ”Paul”
```

The following script can be used to create the table and populate it with sample data...

```
CREATE TABLE Responsible
    ( [ RowType ] VARCHAR(12),
      [ Value ]   VARCHAR(9) )
;

INSERT INTO Responsible
    ( [RowType],
      [ Value ] )
VALUES
    ( 'CustomerID',
      '22' ),
    ( 'CustomerName',
      'ABC'),
    ( 'Responsible',
      'Allan' ),
    ( 'CustomerID',
      '23' ),
    ( 'CustomerName',
      'DEF' ),
    ( 'Responsible',
      'Jessica' ),
    ( 'CustomerID',
      '24' ),
    ( 'CustomerName',
      'GHI' ),
    ( 'Responsible',
      'Paul' );
```

And I would like to get it like a table that looks like this:

```
CustomerID | CustomerName | Responsible  
22         | ABC          | Allan  
23         | DEF          | Jessica  
24         | GHI          | Paul
```

What is the best way forward?

Comment: what the DB engine ? don't you have any field you can group on your table ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You cannot do this.  SQL tables represent *unordered* rows.  Without a column that specifies the ordering, you cannot connect the rows reliably.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is true and false, you still have the saving order (even if not really reliable), look at the table, I don't think you can do anything else than insert, so a join on the output order can probably get what he want

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I'm using Microsoft SQL.

Comment: @FredrikUmea . . . The version of SQL doesn't matter.  The rows are unordered unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: It does not matter which order the records go into the table.  Unless the Questioner somehow knows that the data in the created table will only ever be viewed in the manner suggested in the sample output, we will have to assume that any query made in the future will reference some or all of the fields from the table and that the sort order will be determined based on what fields are the focus of that scenario.  For instance, the sample output appears to be sorted on `CustomerID`, but in some situations you may wish to sort by `CustomerName` or by `Responsible` in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work like this in SQL Server. I don't see any other option, but to use a cursor to go down one row at a time. ***The script below works only in your unique situation.***

**Create the new table**

```
 USE [YOURDATABASE NAME GOES HERE]
 GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_2](
  [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
  [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Responsible] [varchar](50) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO
```

**Insert Data Into Table**

```
 DECLARE @CustomerId INT
 DECLARE @CustomerName VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @Responsible VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE myCursor CURSOR
 FOR SELECT Column2 FROM Table_1;
 OPEN myCursor;
 FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
 INTO @CustomerId;

 FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
 INTO @CustomerName;

 FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
 INTO @Responsible;

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2](CustomerID,CustomerName,Responsible)
        VALUES (@CustomerId,@CustomerName,@Responsible)

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
        INTO @CustomerId;

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
        INTO @CustomerName;

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
        INTO @Responsible;
END
CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

edit, SQL server version :

**Query 10**:

```
select CustomerID, CustomerName, Responsible
from (
select row_number() over(order by k)  as id , v as CustomerID
from t1
where k ='CustomerID') tt1
inner join (
select row_number() over(order by k)  as id , v as CustomerName
from t1
where k ='CustomerName') tt2
on tt1.id = tt2.id
inner join (
select row_number() over(order by k)  as id , v as Responsible
from t1
where k ='Responsible') tt3
on tt1.id = tt3.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03070/1/0)**:

```
| CustomerID | CustomerName | Responsible |
|------------|--------------|-------------|
|         22 |          ABC |       Allan |
|         23 |          DEF |     Jessica |
|         24 |          GHI |        Paul |
```

---

This is what you want I think ?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eb913/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    (`k` varchar(12), `v` varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO t1
    (`k`, `v`)
VALUES
    ('CustomerID', '22'),
    ('CustomerName', 'ABC'),
    ('Responsible', 'Allan'),
    ('CustomerID', '23'),
    ('CustomerName', 'DEF'),
    ('Responsible', 'Jessica'),
    ('CustomerID', '24'),
    ('CustomerName', 'GHI'),
    ('Responsible', 'Paul')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
set @v1 = 0, @v2 = 0, @v3 = 0
```

**Query 2**:

```
select CustomerID, CustomerName, Responsible
from (
    select @v1:= @v1+1 as id , v as CustomerID
    from t1
    where k ='CustomerID'
) tt1
inner join (
    select @v2:= @v2+1 as id , v as CustomerName
    from t1
    where k ='CustomerName'
) tt2
    on tt1.id = tt2.id
inner join (
    select @v3:= @v3+1 as id , v as Responsible
    from t1
    where k ='Responsible'
) tt3
    on tt1.id = tt3.id;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eb913/4/1)**:

```
| CustomerID | CustomerName | Responsible |
|------------|--------------|-------------|
|         22 |          ABC |       Allan |
|         23 |          DEF |     Jessica |
|         24 |          GHI |        Paul |
```

Comment: Many thanks, it’s really appreciated, but with the risk of I’m making a fool of myself. I'm making this in Microsoft SQL not in MySQL. How is the syntax different?